# ibm websphere for mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, websphere, rational-rsa

Tried googling a lot about this could not find Webspear web server for mac.
I was mainly interested in plug-in based server for eclipse Helios for mac, but could not find so thought of at least downloading the server for mac and then configuring the same. This problem all started with the IBM Rational Software Architect available with me supports 32 bit jvm only and not 64 bit which is my current pc configuration.

Any help where I can download a Webspear for mac , either a plug-in based or a proper server.
Or is there a 64 bit support RSA available in the market.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Websphere (not Webspear, although I have to admit that *is* a cool product name) Application Server does not support Mac (at least v7, which is what we're using). It does AIX, HP-UX, iSeries, Linux, Solaris, Windows and z/OS.

Comment: thanks for the spelling and replying , so no way running on mac

Comment: @Ameya: you may well be able to get it to run (I won't say it's impossible since I've never tried it) but I doubt it will be easy and it _definitely_ won't be supported. I suspect you'll be better off running it inside a virtual machine running Linux.